# Counting true occurences in array and binding them to a variable in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, toggle

I have a set of input fields with checkboxes where the user can choose an option. Then it's saved in local storage as true if checked and false if not. The localStorage under key "passengers" looks like this:

```
0: {name: "", child: false, luggage: true}
1: {name: "", child: true, luggage: false}
2: {name: "", child: false, luggage: true}
3: {name: "", child: true, luggage: false}
```

I want to count occurrences of true and store as a number in a variable

```
public luggageCounter: number;
```

I was trying to use

```
this.luggageCounter = countTrue([this.passengers[i].luggage]], true)
console.log(this.luggageCounter)
```

and `const countTrue = (arr, val) => arr.reduce((a, v) => (v === val ? a +1 : a), 0)`

but both of these solutions don't work. I was also thinking about making it easier and toggling the value from HTML by adding code below with [ngClass] and binding it with method in component.ts but also with no success.

```
<div>Extra luggage: {{ passengers[i].luggage ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}<div>
```

Any ideas how to make this simple task work? I'm out of ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution

```js
const data = [
  { name: "", child: false, luggage: true },
  { name: "", child: true, luggage: false },
  { name: "", child: false, luggage: true },
  { name: "", child: true, luggage: false },
];

const total = data.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue.luggage) {
    previousValue += 1;
  }

  return previousValue;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

See

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! :)